# Change dictionary together with input language in Motorola Moto G

Tags: keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean, dictionary, text-prediction, motorola

I have a Motorola Moto G with English set as the default language, but I also selected Polish as an alternative input option. However, when I change the keyboard input to Polish, English dictionary is still used for input correction and hints. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the input text prediction by following:
[Adding a new spell-checker to Motorola Moto G](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60487/adding-a-new-spell-checker-to-motorola-moto-g)

You can't add Polish to the list of Spellcheckers, but too be honest I am not sure where these are used. Google keyboard (which needs to be installed to use the text prediction in this language) lets you download a lot of dictionaries.