# Adding a new spell-checker to Motorola Moto G

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, dictionary, text-prediction, spell-check, motorola-moto-g

Does anybody know how can I add a new spell-checker to Motorola Moto G (it runs Android 4.3 Jelly Bean)?

I have the spell-checker for UK version, but I also would like to use Polish spell-checker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the way I enable additional spell checkers on my Galaxy Nexus which runs on vanilla Android 4.3, I hope it will be the same for your Moto G:

1. Open your app drawer and go to **Settings** > **Language & input**
2. Scroll down to **Keyboard & Input Methods** section: If your Google Keyboard is enabled, tap its settings button, if not, enable it first.
3. On **Google Keyboard Settings** screen, tap **Input languages**

   [image: Language & Input] [image: Google Keyboard settings] [image: Input languages]
4. On **Input languages** screen, scroll down and enable **Polish**. Then tap **Back**.
5. You should be on **Google Keyboard Settings** screen again: Scroll down to **Text Correction** section and tap **Add-on dictionaries**.
6. On **Add-on dictionaries** screen, scroll down and tap **Polski** (which it should say it is ***available***).

   [image: Enable Polish input] [image: Add-on dictionaries] [image: Tap Polski add-on dictionary]
7. Now it should appear a button to **Install** this dictionary: tap it and wait until it is installed.
8. Now, the **Install** button will be replaced for a **Delete** button, and the dictionary status will say ***Installed***. Exit settings screens.
9. Now you can use the Polish spell checker in the phone. Just toggle the language by tapping the **Globe** key to the left of Spacebar in Google Keyboard until it says **Polski** and you'll be ready to use it.

   [image: Ready to install] [image: It's done] [image: Change language input to Polski]

Comment: I had to install Google keyboard first, as there was only Android keyboard by default (AOSC or something similar), but then your guide is perfect. Thanks!